# Update scope value inside service

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I have the following controllers in my app:

Main controller:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.app = {
        amount: 0
    };
}]);
```

Child Controller:

```
app.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var timeLoop = function (amount) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.app.amount++;

            if($scope.app.amount < amount) {
                timeLoop(amount);
            }
        }, 10);
    }
    timeLoop(20);
}]);
```

Another Child Controller:

```
app.controller('AnotherChildCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var timeLoop = function (amount) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.app.amount++;

            if($scope.app.amount < amount) {
                timeLoop(amount);
            }
        }, 10);
    }
    timeLoop(100);
}]);
```

How to do the same thing with the service? I don't want use timeLoop function inside MainCtrl. Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Main Controller:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope','timeOutService', function ($scope,timeOutService) {
    $scope.app = {
        amount: timeOutService.amount 
    };
}]);
```

You could have a `generic service` like this:

```
app.service('timeOutService', function($timeout) {
    this.amount = 0;
    this.timeLoop = function (amount) {
        var that = this;
        $timeout(function () {
            that.amount++;

            if(that.amount < amount) {
                that.timeLoop(amount);
            }
        }, 10);
    }
});
```

And in your `multiple controllers`, you can inject the same:

Child Controller:

```
app.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope','timeOutService', function ($scope,timeOutService) {     console.log("timeOutService", timeOutService);
    timeOutService.timeLoop(20);
}]);
```

Another Child Controller:

```
app.controller('AnotherChildCtrl', ['$scope','timeOutService', function ($scope,timeOutService) { 
    timeOutService.timeLoop(20);
}]);
```

Below is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/40zodv7b/

Comment: thanks. but this will not be updated amount inside main controller

Comment: services are singleton in nature and will be through out the life cycle... why don't you set like this: $scope.app = {
        amount: timeOutService.amount
    } initially in your main controller which would be zero.